# Why the session is working right and after some inactivity, then all of the sudden everything broke?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am a novice in PHP. I programmed this login system for artists, and I had the site working fine, the user logged in, with the sessions working right, but after some period of inactivity, then all of the sudden everything broke. Basically I use a DB, sql, php and html language. Someone told me it could be a GC mechanismm, triggered by possible cyclic objects or arrays. All pages start with:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("functions.php");       
?>
```

Then... regular html and php to call the DB

P.S. I apologize if my question is not well formulated. This is my first question.

```
<?php
include('config/db_connect_quae.php'); 
function getUsersData($id)
{
    $array = array();
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxxx');
    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM artista WHERE `id_autor`='".$id."'");
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
   { 
    $array['id_autor'] = $r['id_autor'];
    $array['nome_autor'] = $r['nome_autor'];
    $array['nome_completo'] = $r['nome_completo'];
    $array['email'] = $r['email'];
    $array['senha'] = $r['senha'];
    $array['url_imagem'] = $r['url_imagem'];    
    $array['descricao'] = $r['descricao'];
    $array['telefone'] = $r['telefone'];
    $array['cidade'] = $r['cidade'];
    $array['estado'] = $r['estado'];
    $array['pais'] = $r['pais'];
    $array['produto_1'] = $r['produto_1'];
    $array['url_prod1'] = $r['url_prod1'];
    $array['total_stream_geral'] = $r['total_stream_geral'];
    $array['valor_total_geral'] = $r['valor_total_geral'];

  }
    return $array; 
}
function getID($usuarioNome)
{
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxxx');
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id_autor` FROM `artista` WHERE `nome_autor`='".$usuarioNome."'");
While($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
return $r['id_autor'];
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post what the error says?

Comment: Thats a problem, there are no errors. Well, I can not see any. The layout just break apart and the session ends. Someone told me it could be the GC mechanism. "The garbage collector is triggered whenever 10,000 possible cyclic objects or arrays are currently in memory". I do have a function that retrieves data from the DB. I am not sure if this array could be cyclic by bad php programming. I will add this function code, who knows this is the real problem.

Comment: Ok, you can check the PHP error log file. If you're on Linux, this file is either `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. Open it and you'll probably see what's causing the error.